# OpenGL immediate mode vs VBO for animated models

Tags: opengl

**Some background info:**
I am working on an opengl game for fun/experience, and in the hope of releasing a small independent game one day. My OpenGL skills are still very limited, and my knowledge does not stretch far beyond OpenGL immediate mode and display lists.

Currently I render my animated models directly in immediate mode (after loading from ms3d file). With a rather large/complex terrain, I can only load and render about 20 animated models consisting of more or less 200 triangles (also texture mapped). As my one goal is to learn more about programming and game development, I feel that it is important for me to learn VBO (vertex buffer object), but as I am a student I am rather short on time. I would rather spend my time implementing more things than learning something potentially difficult (I will of course tackle this in the next holiday).

**My question:** Is it worth it to learn VBO and change the model loader&renderer to use VBO instead of immediate mode calls? Will it be way more efficient? I am thinking of games like Left4Dead, etc., where you may have many detailed models (and even though I am not aiming to be in the same league, I would like some hints as how to improve). I decided not to use display lists as it would have to be reconstructed every frame. Will the same not apply for VBO?

Comment: Learning vertex arrays is worth it alone for the simple fact that immediate mode has been removed from OpenGL-3 and never existed for OpenGL-ES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it worth it to learn VBO and change the model loader&renderer to use VBO instead of immediate mode calls?

VBO will be more efficient. **HOWEVER** you can also speed up animation using display lists, so you can skip VBO and use display lists. If you're coding for fun and for yourself, there's little reason to chase after most recent technology. There are more computers that support OpenGL 2, than computers that support OpenGL 4.

Regardless of OpenGL version you use shaders are worth investigating - GLSL is available since OpenGL 2.0, and it is quite powerful.

Anyway, if you're interested in using OpenGL/shaders you might want to download and examine NVIdia OPenGL SDK. It contains interesting examples, for example animating skinned model using vertex shaders and display lists.

> I decided not to use display lists as it would have to be reconstructed every frame.

If they "would have to be reconstructed every frame", then you're not approaching problem properly  (unless your geometry is completely dynamic and changes topology every frame). Either split model into parts that do not need reconstruction, or put the whole thing into single display list and animate parts using vertex shader.

Comment: I guess that's true. Didn't think of it that way (splitting the model into parts). I think this pretty much answers my question. I will look into NVidia OpenGL SDK as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving it a try. Like most other things in OpenGL, it looked really confusing and scary to me, too, but it only took me 1 day to work through some examples and figure out how to do it.

It's difficult to say whether it will offer you a speed-up or not, since we don't know exactly what you're trying to do or on what hardware, but think of it this way: you can load static data (like scenery, if it isn't deformable) onto the card once and not reload it ever again. That means hundreds or thousands of vertices you don't resend every frame. This is usually a pretty significant win. If you're on MacOS X, I found [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_vertexdata/opengl_vertexdata.html) to be very helpful. It's probably helpful even if you're not on OS X, as there's nothing Mac-specific in the code samples.

Comment: Thanks. I already have my static scenery implemented with display lists. There is definitely a bottle-neck to the GPU, but I don't see how using VBO will solve this problem, as I will have to rebuild the models after the animations took place. I'm working on windows, but I will have a look at that page anyway. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That link looks really helpful by the way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As always with technology, things have moved on. You appear to be using the OpenGL2 (or earlier) fixed function architecture. Modern OpenGL (it's up to 4.x) use programmable pipelines (known as shaders). You may want to consider looking into newer OpenGL APIs, they aren't too hard to learn (there's lots of stuff on-line) and you can get quite creative in the rendering of models.

If you want to keep to the earlier versions of OpenGL, maybe you've got some old hardware, then definately learn about VBOs. It may not always be the best option, but it can be the optimal solution for certain types of geometry. As with any API, the more you know about it the better you can utilise the available features.

Comment: I have no specific reason to try and keep older versions of OpenGL. I have read up on shaders before but didn't get very far. I think I should try and spend some time on it as soon as I can. Will the use of shaders eliminate the need for VBO, or can the two work together? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, you don't possibly have a link to an intro level shader tutorial lying around by any chance? Or know of a helpful website? If not, don't stress to look for one, I'll get around to it myself.

Comment: @Denzil here's a tutorial I found helpful: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/